# nhibernate audit trigger error

Tags: nhibernate, triggers, audit

I'm using triggers on my sql database to capture change information for a table, it seems to be having a problem with nhibernate though.

The table has a few columns and primary keys and triggers on it. The triggers look like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Instrument_update] ON [dbo].[Instrument] FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN
  INSERT [MyAudit].[audit].[Instrument]
  SELECT 'Updated', i.*
    FROM inserted
   INNER JOIN [MyAudit].[dbo].[Instrument] i ON inserted.[InstrumentID] = i.[InstrumentID]
END
```

Basically on every change we copy the row into the audit table. I have tested and if I modify the data directly through sql management studio triggers function correctly and I get data written to the audit table, however if i update through my app I get the following:

> NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException
>   was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Row was updated or deleted by
>   another transaction (or unsaved-value
>   mapping was incorrect)

I assume this is because the trigger updates another table in another database, is there anyway to make nhibernate ignore this as the change will not affect any of its data, in our mappings we have no reference to this audit data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the trigger was causing Nhibernate to do two identical update calls for some reason. The solution was to SET NOCOUNT ON inside the trigger. Still not sure though why nhibernate makes two updates!